# D.Gray- man Hallow. Remake? Or continuation?

Tags: d-gray-man

I'm not sure if this is a remake of the old D.Gray man or if this is a continuation of where the anime left off. Does anyone know anything about this anime? And maybe have a credible source to link?

Comment: Have you tried wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.Gray-man

Comment: Nope. I saw it in my stream queue but ran off to do homework. And then I had work in the morning so I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per [Hakase's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34118/d-gray-man-hallow-remake-or-continuation#comment46956_34118) link to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.Gray-man#Anime)

> A new TV anime series was announced at Shueisha's 2016 Jump Festa event. The anime will feature a new cast, with Ayumu Murase voicing Allen Walker and Shinnosuke Tachibana voicing Howard Link. Despite the changes, **the series creator has stated that the new series will continue from where the first left off, rather than being a reboot.** The new series, titled D.Gray-man Hallow, is directed by Yoshiharu Ashino and written by Michiko Yokote, Tatsuto Higuchi and Kenichi Yamashita, featuring character designs by Yosuke Kabashima and music by Kaoru Wada. It will begin airing on July 4, 2016, having a total of 13 episodes.

following Wikipedia's citation and the source on that page to [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2015-12-23/katsura-hoshino-new-d.gray-man-anime-story-is-continuation/.96772) this comes from the D.Gray-man's mangaka Katsura Hoshino on her Instagram account

> Thanks to everyone who went to the D.Gray-man stage today. As was said in the announcement, a new series has been green-lit. **Because the staff will be completely different, the story will be a continuation,** but I think it will become a completely new D.Gray-man anime. Thank you for everyone who's supported me until now.

Comment: Thanks for the streamline @memor-x do you know how many episodes it is?

Comment: @KazRodgers that's in the answer which too came from WIkipedia

Comment: Zomg! I'm sorry I didn't even get to read it all the way. I'm super scatter brained today :-(